# HTML Input (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please help me

I have a script which works on First Page Load, And when i use the function of this script again is doesn't work until i refresh the page, Means i want this script to work always, Not only when i will refresh the page, here is the script:

---

```
$(function(){
    var fullEmail = $('#email').val();
    console.log(fullEmail.length);
    if(fullEmail.length>15)
    {  
        textDot = fullEmail.substr(0, 14)+'...';
        $('#email').val(textDot); 
    }

    var oldText = $('#email').val();
    $('#email').bind({ 
     mouseover : function () {
        $('#email').val(fullEmail);
     },
     mouseout: function () {
        $('#email').val(oldText);
     }
     });     
});
```

---

thanks in advance..

Comment: need some clarification.  do you need to call this function when something happens?  what's the context of this script?

Comment: What do you mean by "work always?"

Comment: this is the script for a HTML input, we have a HTML input(for email) in our website, we have limited space for input width, we created this script to work like, if the email is long then 15 letters then it will show "..." after 15 letters and when we click on input it shows full email address to copy/paste.

Comment: The purpose for creating this script was:

Email– if email or URL is too long to fit, show "..." (3 dots) after 15 letters and when clicked, the text changes into text-box and user can copy/paste the full email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a [JSFiddle to demonstrate this](http://jsfiddle.net/jyTPt/). When you type in the email and then leave the input box, it shortens. When you re-enter the input box it expands back to its full length...

```
$('#email').bind('change', function () {
    $self = $(this);
    var fullEmail = $self.val();
    var shortEmail = fullEmail;
    if(fullEmail.length > 15) {  
        shortEmail = fullEmail.substr(0, 14)+'...';
        $self.val(shortEmail );
    }

    $self.bind({
        focus: function () {
            $self.val(fullEmail);
        },
        blur: function () {
            $self.val(shortEmail);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: My client says: if email is too long to fit, show "..." (3 dots) after 15 letters and when clicked, the text changes into text-box and user can copy/paste the full email address.

Comment: you can see here in Business card.

http://hyindia.com/yoyavo/yavo_details.html

Comment: this script doesn't work mostly until i refresh the page..!

Answer (score 0):

```
var oldText;
var fullEmail;
function smt(){
     fullEmail = $('#email').val();
        console.log(fullEmail.length);
        if(fullEmail.length>15)
        {  
            textDot = fullEmail.substr(0, 14)+'...';
            $('#email').val(textDot); 
        }

        oldText = $('#email').val();
}    

$(function(){

    $('#email').bind({ 
     mouseover : function () {
        smt();
        $('#email').val(fullEmail);
     },
     mouseout: function () {
        smt();
        $('#email').val(oldText);
     }
     });     
});
```